# Numpy array bigger than the total size of images it is made up of

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to convert a directory of RGB images to a numpy array but the resulting array is way bigger than the sum of sizes of all the images put together. What is going on here?

Comment: Can you give the code that you use to merge them and the sizes of the inputs and outputs?

Comment: That would be too tedious, I just want to know if it's a possibility at all or if I might be doing something erroneous.

Comment: Do you mean you have a few JPEGs of 30kB each and they made 6MB in Numpy?

Comment: What's the image format?

Comment: Image format is `png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah I have few 1000s of 2-3 MB `png`s that generate GBs of numpy array.

Comment: Another thing to look at is dtype

Comment: sorry it didn't.

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with? It just shows that a 44kB file on disk can correspond to a 44MB file in memory, i.e. 1000 times bigger, because of compression.

Answer (score 2):

That's because image files are usually compressed, which means that the stored data will be smaller than the original file containing all pixel data, when you open a image using PIL, for example, you'll get access to all RGB values of all pixels, so, there's more data 'cus it's uncompressed.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is *compression*, and in the case of [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Compression), *filtering*. The longer answer is...

Imagine you make a screen-grab of your lovely 5K screen of 5120x2880 pixels. You would expect that to be this size and shape in Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

# Mock a screen-grab on 5120x2880 screen
grab = np.zeros((2880,5120,3), np.uint8)
```

Now let's get the size of it:

```
print(grab.nbytes)
```

and it is 44236800, i.e. 44MB

Now let's save that as a PNG:

```
from PIL import Image
Image.fromarray(grab).save('result.png')
```

and check its size:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  43010 18 Mar 09:14 result.png
```

so, it's 43kB, or 1000x smaller because of compression and filtering.

---

I admit that the case above is extreme, because a blank screen is very compressible, but in fact, it could have been worse. Imagine the screen was a high-depth 16-bit affair, and it captured an alpha channel as well. In that case, you'd have:

```
grab = np.zeros((2880,5120,4), np.uint16)
print(grab.nbytes)
```

Prints:

```
117964800      i.e. 117MB!
```